# How can I use a variable for the "expected" attribute of junit @Test?

Tags: java, generics, junit

I am trying to write a generic test class, but I can't find a generic way to specify the `expected` attribute of the `@Test` annotation. Here's a cut-down version of my code:

```
public class MyTest<T extends Throwable> {
    Class<T> clazz; // set in constructor

    @Test(expected=clazz)
    public void test() { 
    }
}
```

The compiler error I'm getting for the use of `clazz` is:

> The value for annotation attribute Test.expected must be a class literal

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Use a try/catch block and test using `.getClass()` in catch?

Answer (score 3):

it's not a junit problem. you just can't use variables in java annotations. i don't know what exactly you try to achieve but expected exceptions can be also set using junit rules. and they can be inherited

Answer (score 1):

You could use JUnit's [ExpectedException.](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html)

```
public class MyTest<T extends Throwable> {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    Class<T> clazz; // set in constructor

    @Test
    public void test() {
        thrown.expect(clazz); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem from a testing perspective. You have written a unit test that you expect to fail, but you don't know how it's going to fail until the test is run. I think you need to create better unit tests. If the test is going to fail, you should definitely know how you expect it to fail. In fact, you should be ensuring that it always fails the exact same way.